# Arduino conversions in C

Tags: c, arduino

```
void digitalClockDisplay(){
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  Serial.println(); 


}



void printDigits(int digits){
  // utility function for digital clock display: prints preceding colon and leading 0
  Serial.print(":");
  if(digits < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}

//I tried something like this

//void time(){

//char* hr = (char*)hour();

//Serial.println(hr);

//}
//But when I print it it gives a whole bunch of jibberish
```

Here are the two functions I'm using what I'm trying to do is make a function like the digitalClockDisplay function but one that returns the hour:minute as a char* once I have that I want to be able to compare that to another char*

Comment: can you provide the code that calls digitalClockDisplay? Did you call Serial.begin(<port>) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hour()` seems to be returning a `int`, so

```
char* hr = (char*)hour();
Serial.println(hr);
```

casts a `int` to a pointer and then sends the bytes at that (meaningless) address to `Serial`.

You probably want something like:

```
char hr[8];
snprintf(hr,8,"%i:%02i",hour(),minute());
Serial.println(hr);
```